# How to display the elements of a queue implemented using linked list in c?

Tags: c, queue

I implemented the queue using linked list. The display function is only printing the last element. But I want to display all the elements. Can somebody correct it? What are the other ways to write the display function? Is the node declaration wrong?

My code is as follows:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int QueueElement;
typedef enum {TRUE,FALSE} Boolean;

typedef struct node{
    QueueElement entry;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct{
    int count;
    Boolean full;
    Node *front;
    Node *rear;
} Queue;

void createQueue(Queue *q){
    q->count=0;
    q->front=q->rear=NULL;
    q->full=FALSE;
}

Boolean IsFull(Queue *q){
    return (q->full);
}

Boolean IsEmpty(Queue *q){
    return (q->front==NULL && q->rear==NULL);
}

void insert(QueueElement x,Queue *q){
    Node *np;
    np=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(np==NULL){
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        q->full=TRUE;
    }
    else{
        np->entry=x;
        np->next=NULL;
        if(IsEmpty(q))
            q->front=q->rear=np;
        else{
            q->rear->next=np;
            np=q->rear;
        }
        ++q->count;
        printf("Inserted %d\n", x);
    }
}

void Remove(Queue *q){
    Node *np;
    if(IsEmpty(q))
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
    else{
        q->count--;
        int x=q->front->entry;
        np=q->front;
        q->front=q->front->next;
        if(q->front==NULL)
            q->rear=NULL;
        free(np);
        printf("Removed %d\n",x);
    }
}

void display(Queue q){
    //if(IsEmpty(q))
       // printf("Queue is empty\n");

    Node *iter = q.front;
    while(iter) {
        printf("%d ", iter->entry);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Queue q;
    createQueue(&q);
    Remove(&q);
    insert(1,&q);
    insert(2,&q);
    insert(3,&q);
    insert(4,&q);
    Remove(&q);
    display(q);

    return 0;
}
```

**My display function is as follows:**

```
void display(Queue q){
    //if(IsEmpty(q))
    //    printf("Queue is empty\n");

    Node *iter = q.front;

    while(iter) {
        printf("%d ", iter->entry);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ensured that your queue structure itself is correct and that front and all the pointers point to the right place?

Comment: You will receive more help if you indent your code properly.

Comment: You don't update `q->rear` in the `insert` function for insertions after the first one.

Comment: This line `np=q->rear;` looks strange to me. Did you intend to do `q->rear=np;` ?

Comment: One other problem: `Remove` causes memory leaks as `free(np)` is only called when the very last element is removed.

Comment: @kaylum That `free(np)` isn't part of the `if(q->front==NULL)` block, note no brackets. The spacing screwed me up too.

Comment: @nickelpro Oh you're right. The incorrect indentation got me.

Comment: @4386427 yeah . I'm little bit confused.

Comment: @kaylum Yeah. I forgot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments already spotted the problem, but just to give this an answer:

In the `insert` function the following line is the problem:

```
np=q->rear;
```

Should be:

```
q->rear=np;
```

Which works as expected:

```
Queue is empty
Inserted 1
Inserted 2
Inserted 3
Inserted 4
Removed 1
2 3 4
```

Comment: @Nithur I'm glad! Please accept the answer if it fully answered your question